# How can i make certain div elements non draggable using Dragula for Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, dragula, ng2-dragula

I have been able to successfully integrate `ng2-dragula` with my project, but I still cannot figure out how to make some divs `non draggable`.

I have tried to use some `css` and also htmls `draggable="false"` for the div but no success. It seems like whatever I put, dragula will insert its directives afterwards and override everything. Maybe I am wrong...

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

For example:

```
<div [dragula]="'group'">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div [dragula]="'group'">
        <div>3</div>
        <div class="donotdrag">4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make the `div` with class **donotdrag** non draggable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [invalid](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsinvalid) options to do that.

Just set options via [dragulaService.setOptions](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula#dragulaservicesetoptionsname-options) in your component constructor like:

```
dragulaService.setOptions('group', {
  invalid: (el, handle) => el.classList.contains('donotdrag')
});
```

**[Demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/twa04CjO51REH8tcmc0B?p=preview)**

Comment: @Brian Put `!` front of `el.classList.contains('donotdrag')` like `!el.classList.contains('donotdrag')`

Comment: Also, if you are getting error - "BAG_NAME is already exists", use `viewProviders: [DragulaService]` in your component, it should fix the issue.